# What defines the scope of a kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I'm looking to try out using Kafka for an existing system, to replace an older message protocol.  Currently we have a number of types of messages (hundreds) used to communicate among ~40 applications.  Some are asynchronous at high rates and some are based upon request from user/events.

Now looking at Kafka, it breaks out topics and partitions etc.  But I'm a bit confused as to what constitutes a topic.  Does every type of message my applications produce get their own topic allowing hundreds of topics, or do I cluster them together to related message types?  If the second answer, is it bad practice for an application to read a message and drop it when its contents are not what its looking for?

I'm also in a dilemma where there will be upwards of 10 copies of a single application (a display), all of which getting a very large amount of data (in form of a light weight video stream of sorts) and would be sending out user commands on each particular node.  Would Kafka be a sufficient form of communication for this?  Assuming that at most 10, but sometimes these particular applications may not have the desire to get the video stream at all times.

A third and final question: I read a bit about replay-ability of messages.  Is this only within a single topic, or can the replay-ability go over a slew of different topics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka itself doesn't care about "types" of message. The only type it knows about are bytes, meaning that you are completely flexible to how you will serialize your datasets. Note, however that the default max message size is just 1MB, so "streaming video/images/media" is arguably the wrong use case for Kafka alone. A protocol like RTMP would probably make more sense

Kafka consumer groups scale horizontally, not in response to load. Consumers poll data at a rate at which they can process. If they don't need data, then they can be stopped, if they need to reprocess data, they can be independently seeked